# Low quality questions - No Comment Deleted

Tags: discussion

I understand that it is misuse of flags to flag technical inaccuracies, and instead flags are meant for non-answers, spam, etc. In the case of technically incorrect answer, the best course of action is typically downvoting.

My question then regards reviewing Low Quality posts. It isn't infrequent that a post will show up in the "Low Quality Posts" queue that is technically inaccurate.

Is it acceptable to "Recommend Deletion" > "No Comment Needed" on these posts? Or should a downvote be the only course of action taken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a question is flat-out wrong on top of being exceedingly brief, in poor English, or whatever, by all means vote to recommend deletion.

If it looks beautiful except for being wrong, I'd stick with downvotes and comments.

Comment: +1 for not making science out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

A downvote should be the solution in the case the post is **not useful**. As in:

- It is *technically correct*, but isn't clear.
- It is *technically correct*, but is only a link or is of some other value.
- It is *technically **incorrect***, but is of some value to the original question.

Deletion is reserved for:

- Posts which are actively harmful.
- Posts with obvious, gaping security holes.
- Posts which have nothing to do with the original question.
- Spam.
- Inflammatory
- Comments/Other Questions
- Etc

It all depends on the individual post you're reviewing.